# Connection issues with Hibernate and Postgresql

Tags: hibernate, postgresql, vaadin, connection-pooling, postgresql-9.1

I'm using Hibernate 4.3.8 with PostgreSQL database for the development of a web application using Vaadin 7.4.4.

I'm facing some problems that, honestly, I think they are Connection related problems.

Randomly, when I try to log into my webapp, the browser gets stuck while "loading", and it doesn't go further. This only stops when I restart the PostgreSQL service from the Server (ubuntu).

What I have been struggling with is the hibernate configuration file trying to set up a Connection Pool, but I haven't got success: I've tried with hibernate's built-in connection pool (not introducing any pool configuration within the hibernate.cfg.xml, and as it's said, this should not be used in production mode), DBCP and C3p0.

I attach the hibernate.cfg.xml file just in case someone lends me a hand:

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?> <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration
        PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>

    <session-factory>

        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

        <!-- POSTGRESQL -->
            <!-- POSTGRESQL Database connection settings -->
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>

            <!-- Server config -->
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://_server-url_</property>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username">_user_</property>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password">_pass_</property>

            <!-- POSTGRESQL SQL Dialect -->
            <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
        <!-- POSTGRESQL -->

        <!-- C3p0 pool connection manager -->
<!--         <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property> -->
<!--         <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">1000</property> -->
<!--         <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">0</property> -->
<!--         <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">100</property> -->
<!--         <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">3000</property> -->

        <!--connection pool--> 
<!--        <property name="hibernate.dbcp.maxActive">10</property>  -->
<!--        <property name="hibernate.dbcp.whenExhaustedAction">1</property>  -->
<!--        <property name="hibernate.dbcp.maxWait">20000</property>  -->
<!--        <property name="hibernate.dbcp.maxIdle">10</property>  -->

        <!-- prepared statement cache--> 
<!--        <property name="hibernate.dbcp.ps.maxActive">10</property>  -->
<!--        <property name="hibernate.dbcp.ps.whenExhaustedAction">1</property>  -->
<!--        <property name="hibernate.dbcp.ps.maxWait">20000</property>  -->
<!--        <property name="hibernate.dbcp.ps.maxIdle">10</property>  -->

        <!-- optional query to validate pooled connections:--> 
<!--        <property name="hibernate.dbcp.validationQuery">select 1</property>  -->
<!--        <property name="hibernate.dbcp.testOnBorrow">true</property>  -->
<!--        <property name="hibernate.dbcp.testOnReturn">true</property>  -->

        <!-- SQL to stdout logging -->
<!--         <property name="show_sql">true</property> -->
<!--         <property name="format_sql">true</property> -->
<!--         <property name="use_sql_comments">true</property> -->


        <!-- class mappings go here ... -->

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

As you can see, C3p0 and DBCP config lines are commented.

At this point, I don't know whether this problem is related to Hibernate or, perhaps, related to some aspect of PostgreSQL server.

Could anybody help me out? Thank you in advance!

**EDIT 1**

@CraigRinger Perhaps I'm managing something wrong? To manage database access, I've got a PtDAO class, from where I perform every access to the data base via Hibernate (commonly I use HQL). It follows Singleton pattern.

The constructor is who opens hibernate's configuration file and opens session:

```
    private PtDao() {

    Configuration configuration = new Configuration()
            .configure("hibernate.cfg.xml"); // configures settings from
                                                // hibernate.cfg.xml

    StandardServiceRegistryBuilder serviceRegistryBuilder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder();

    // If you miss the below line then it will complain about a missing
    // dialect setting
    serviceRegistryBuilder.applySettings(configuration.getProperties());

    serviceRegistry = serviceRegistryBuilder.build();

    factory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);

    this.openSession();

}
```

Methods to open/close session and begin/commit/rollback transaction:

```
private void openSession() {
    session = factory.openSession();
}

public void closeSession() {
    session.close();
}

private void beginTransaction() {
    this.tx = null;
    this.tx = session.beginTransaction();
}

private void commitTransaction() {
    this.tx.commit();
}

private void rollbackTransaction() {
    if (this.tx != null)
        this.tx.rollback();
}
```

Am I doing something wrong with the connection? I've realised that I never call to closeSession(), should I do it when the user presses the logout button?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Anything of interest in the PostgreSQL log files?

Comment: where can I find log files in my server?

Comment: Within my log file there are a couple of lines which are repeated continuously: "unexpected EOF on client connection" and "could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer" (the first one more often than the second one). @CraigRinger

Comment: OK, so it sounds like Java-side issues.